# Display DataGridView from multiple sources in ACCESS

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, join, datagridview

I want to display a DataGridView which its data is from one table and to add an additional column from another table from ACCESS database.

This is my code:

```
string PathDB6 = Application.StartupPath + @"\PcStore.ACCDB";
OleDbConnection connection6 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + PathDB6 + ";Persist Security Info=False;");
OleDbDataAdapter ada6 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM CustomersOrdersDetail", connection6);
DataSet set6 = new DataSet();
ada6.Fill(set6, "CustomersOrdersDetail");
tabSearchCustomerOrder = new DataTable();
tabSearchCustomerOrder = set6.Tables["CustomersOrdersDetail"];
dgvCustomerOrderDetail.DataSource = tabSearchCustomerOrder;
dgvCustomerOrderDetail.Sort(dgvCustomerOrderDetail.Columns["OrderID"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
dgvCustomerOrderDetail.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

But I don't know how to select an additional column from another table to the DataGridView I mentioned above (dgvCustomerOrderDetail) .

I'm using **OLEDB** in **c#**

thank you in advance.

My tables and fields:

Table number 1 : "Customers Orders Detail"

[Customers Orders Detail Table fields](http://image.prntscr.com/image/2073ac18e47f45db9a4c074a73a95907.png)

Table number 2 : "Customers Orders"

[Customers Orders Table fields](http://image.prntscr.com/image/5399d055c05e473a812874b67d8135ea.png)

In my dgv, I have all the data of the table "CustomersOrdersDetail", I want to add the column WorkerApproved from the 2nd table to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to display the additional column to the DataGridView, you need to update your SQL accordingly to have this other column.

For example, considering that your second table is a Customers table and you want to display the email address of this customer as the additional column:

```
string sql = "SELECT CustomersOrdersDetail.*, Customers.Email 
FROM CustomersOrdersDetail INNER JOIN Customers on CustomersOrdersDetail.ID = Customers.ID";
```

You can learn more on [INNER JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208854(v=office.12).aspx)

Once you will fill your dataset, you should see the additional Email column.

So, in your case (not checked):

```
string sql = "SELECT CustomersOrdersDetail.*, CustomersOrders.WorkerApproved
FROM CustomersOrdersDetail INNER JOIN CustomersOrders on
CustomersOrdersDetail.CustomerID = CustomersOrders.CustomerID AND
CustomersOrdersDetail.OrderID = CustomersOrders.OrderID";
```

Comment: Inner Join : "Combines records from two tables whenever there are matching values in a common field."

I don't have a common field , So what can i do ?

Comment: if you do not have any fields in common, so how can you relate 2 records from 2 different tables. That's not clear to me, please post the relevant tables and their fields so I can help.

Comment: Not like that, please update your post. For each table, list the relevant fields and give a short description for each table.

Comment: Table number 1 : "Customers Orders Detail" http://image.prntscr.com/image/2073ac18e47f45db9a4c074a73a95907.png

Table number 2 : "Customers Orders" http://image.prntscr.com/image/5399d055c05e473a812874b67d8135ea.png

In my dgv I have all the data of the table "CustomersOrdersDetail", I want to add the column WorkerApproved from table 2 to it.

Comment: You common fields are CustomerID and OrderID.

Comment: Worked Like A Charm , Thank you very much.